# Date Changed event is triggered only on increment in date but not on decrementing

Tags: android

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            AlarmUtility alarmUtility = new AlarmUtility();
            alarmUtility.setAlarm(context.getApplicationContext());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Date Changed !!!!!!!!!!", 10000).show();
        }
      }
}
```

Change the date to tomorrow triggers the event but again reducing it to today doesnt trigger any events.

Am i doing anything wrong? Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems this is an [unresolved issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2880)

Comment: you mean its a bug in android? Is there any work around to fix in my app?